# Error on Tkinter Canvas when trying to update from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I've coded my own version of the 2048 game in Python. It works pretty well when I execute it from it's main class:

```
class _2048:
    def __init__(self):
    ...
...
...
test = _2048()
```

This class also has the Tkinter and Tkinter.Canvas objects, and I have another class called Tile where I have all the functions relative to every single tile.

Now I'm trying to code a class that controls the game automatically. Let me explain: In the 2048 class I have binded up, down, right and left arrow keys. They share the same callback function, where I use the event.keycode value to decide what to do. To simulate this events I created a class called Kevent that looks like it follows:

```
class Kevent:
    def __init__(self, mov):
        if(mov=="n"):
            self.keycode = 38
        elif(mov=="s"):
            self.keycode = 40
        elif(mov=="e"):
            self.keycode = 39
        elif(mov=="w"):
            self.keycode = 37
```

(I know it isn't very beautiful). Finally I have the Test class, where I have an instance of the _2048 class and an instance of the Kevent class:

```
class Test:
    joc: _2048
    event: Kevent
    def __init__(self):
        self.joc = _2048()
        self.event = Kevent("s")
        sleep(1)
        self.joc.tecla(self.event)
test = Test()
```

When I run the above code it happens nothing, but when I close the 2048 window I get the following error:

```
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
```

It fails inside this function (inside the Tile class) where I move the elements in my 2048's Canvas:

```
    def mou_canvas(self, canvas):
        # moviment is a class where I control the moves of the "self" tile
        moviment = self.moviment
        # quadrat is the Canvas id for the square of the tile
        quadrat = self.getQuadrat()
        # text is the Canvas id for the text inside the tile
        text = self.getText()

        (dx,dy) = moviment.getMov()
        score = 0

        # If the tile can move
        if(moviment.getPot_moure()):
            canvas.move(quadrat, 100*dx, 100*dy)  # <---- The error occurs in this line
            canvas.move(text, 100*dx, 100*dy)
            canvas.update_idletasks()

        # If there is a collision
        if(moviment.getColisiona()):
            mult = moviment.getMult_colisio()
            if(mult == 0):
                canvas.delete(quadrat)
                canvas.delete(text)
            else:
                score = self.getNum()*2
                self.setNum(score)
                canvas.tag_raise(quadrat)
                canvas.tag_raise(text)
                fontsize = 30 if(score<1024) else 20 if(score<100000) else 15
                canvas.itemconfig(text, text=str(self.getNum()), font=("Arial Black", fontsize))

        self.moviment.reset()

        return score
```

I imagine that the solution must be really easy, but I've spent several hours with the problem and haven't found it.

EDIT: I solved the problem by executing the _2048 class in a new thread:

```
class _2048(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        # Everything I had in old __init__ method
        ...
...
...
```

Comment: ***TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"***: Your canvas was destroyed! How do you call `def mou_canvas(self, canvas):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by executing the _2048 class in a new thread:

```
class _2048(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        # Everything I had in old __init__ method
        ...
...
...
```